# jsViews: bind function/helper to DOM event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsviews

I am trying to remove an element from a list that is being displayed with a `{^{for}}` loop by clicking an `<i>` element. This could of course be achieved through jQuery's `.on` as seen here: [Todos example, Source Line 138](http://borismoore.github.io/jsviews/demos/step-by-step/10_todos.html)

But I would like a jQuery-free approach or at least less binding. So I checked if the (e.g.) `onclick` would help with the following:

```
<i onclick="console.dir(this);">delete</i>
```

But I found nothing helpful in the console.

Is there a way to retrieve jsViews compatible data from within the `onclick`?
And if not: Is there a way to bind a helper or something to a DOM event? I'm imagining something like:

```
<i onclick=~deleteItem>delete</i>
```

Comment: I now use `<i onclick="var x = $.view(this); x.data.Delete(); $.observable(x.parent.data).remove(x.index, 1);">delete</i>` - it requires no jQuery or other binding. [The object has a `Delete` method that does a server call.] Binding a helper to a DOM event still would be a nice feature.

Comment: You can now do <i data-link="{on ~deleteItem}">delete</i> to call a helper, or <i data-link="{on deleteItem}">delete</i> to call a data method. <i data-link="{on 'keyup' ~update}">update</i>, for example, lets you choose the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right, you use `$.view(this)` (where `this` is the HTML element instance) to get the view, and from there you can get the data, and a lot more.

You might be interested in this new 'tutorial sequence' - http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link - and especially this page http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/hover - which relates to different ways of hooking up to DOM events.